# QuantStrat signals and orders in R

Tags: r, quantmod, quantstrat

I have Bid-Ask ticks for these 3 isins. I have imported this data and converted to xts objects (I think this part is right). Now I have to add my buy/sell signals and orders. In this case I have a a data table with the columns (isin, date to buy, date to sell). I don't know how to make this a signal and execute the orders. Any help or guide please?

```
#import data and convert it to xts objects
isin1=fread("isin1.csv",header=TRUE, sep=";",fill=TRUE)
isin1<-xts(isin1[,-1])
isin2=fread("isin1.csv",header=TRUE, sep=";",fill=TRUE)
isin2<-xts(isin1[,-1])
isin3=fread("isin1.csv",header=TRUE, sep=";",fill=TRUE)
isin3<-xts(isin1[,-1])

initDate="2017-02-23"
from="2017-02-23"
to="2017-09-22"
options(width=70)

currency('EUR')
Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")
symbols<-c("isin1","isin2","isin3")

for(symbol in symbols){ 
  stock(symbol, currency="EUR",multiplier=1) 
} 

#trade sizing and initial equity settings
tradeSize <- 100000
initEq <- tradeSize*length(symbols)

strategy.st <- portfolio.st <- account.st <- "test"

rm.strat(strategy.st)

initPortf(portfolio.st, symbols=symbols, initDate=initDate, currency='EUR')

initAcct(account.st, portfolios=portfolio.st, initDate=initDate, 
currency='EUR',initEq=initEq)

initOrders(portfolio.st, initDate=initDate)

strategy(strategy.st, store=TRUE)

#ADD RULES/SIGNALS/INDICATORS
```

Answer (score 0):

you can build Indicators then signals and rules for moving between positions. Then apply your strategy over your portfolio.
After that you can deduce the profit/loss factors.
I have wrote detailed example [here](http://rpubs.com/Mohammed/Trading_Basics)